# string variable is empty after filled

Tags: node.js

`enc_audio` was filled in `req.on('data' ...)` block but then outside this block `enc_audio` is empty.

Code :

```
else if (url === '/Devices/Audio/audio.php'
) {
        req.on('data', data => {
            enc_audio += data.toString();
            console.log(enc_audio); // Working          
        });                                                                                             res.end();                                      console.log(enc_audio); // not working
        console.log('Length :'+enc_audio.length); // length 0 why ?
        console.log(enc_audio); // empty 
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's a callback and will execute async. You can wrap this function and return a promise and then `await` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment you can promisify that into a function as below:

```js
function getData(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.on('data', data => {
            resolve(data.toString());
        });
        // you should handle the error here
    });
}

enc_audio += await getData(req);
res.end();
console.log(enc_audio);
console.log('Length :'+enc_audio.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of async execution. This is what is happening here:

1. The Callback Blocks are executed but node by default does not wait for the results to return (async).
2. It straight moves to next block and hence length 0". To execute it properly you can use async-await syntax.

```
req.on('data', async data => {
            await enc_audio += data.toString();
            console.log(enc_audio); // Working          
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

`req.on` is an asynchronous call. So what happens is that the following code block

```js
data => {
  enc_audio += data.toString();
  console.log(enc_audio); // Working          
}
```

will be called after all synchronous calls (For example, console.log) have been made. This is the nature of JavaScript's event loop. A good video explaining this can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

To fix this, read @Dominik's comment.